# Error code 0:npm install -g phonegap

Tags: node.js, cordova

I tried `npm install -g phonegap` and and after few seconds i will find this error and warning
[image].

and after few minutes again `Socket hang up`
[image]

And in the end it is not installed
[image]

I should mention i tried this

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and even

```
  npm config set registry https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/master
```

,but non of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you can download https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/master from your browser, that means your network is ok.

I think the problem is because the github server delay the response to prevent DDos attack.

You can change the following default values:

```
fetch-retries = 2
fetch-retry-factor = 10
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 60000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 10000
```

example:

```
npm config set fetch-retries 4
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 60000
```